# Implementing itemize in multi column table in Latex

Tags: tables, itemize, multicolumn, bullets

I am trying to create a multicolumn table for an IEEE conference paper I am currently writing.

The desired column format is given below:

[image]

I have written a code that closely gives me the desired table but I am not able to put bullet points in the 2nd and 3rd column of the table.

```
\begin{table*}[htbp]
\caption{Converter Operation Under Various Component Failure}

\begin{center}
\begin{itemize}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|p{0.4\linewidth}| p{0.4\linewidth}| } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{4em}{\textbf{Device}}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Type of Failure}} \\
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Open Circuit failure (OCF)}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Short Circuit failure (SCF)}}  \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{4em}{\textbf{Main Switch}} & \item Converter operation possible without any additional components.  & \item Converter operation possible with fuse incorporated in each phase between switch and inductor of that phase.  \\ 
& \item Current and voltage stresses on other phases increases. & \item Current and voltage stresses on other phases increases. \\
```

The resulted table from this above code is:

[image]

Can anyone please help me in adding the bullets in the 2nd and 3rd column of the table.

Also, can anyone tell me how to nest itemize environment in each column?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a compilable code, not screenshots of the code. One obvious error is that the `itemize` environment should be nested in each cell where you want to have the bullets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier just to add a `\textbullet` in every row, assuming you want the left and right sides synchronized.

Otherwise, you need to put the entire itemize inside a minipage inside a column (the minipage gets rid of the gaps at the top and bottom).  One could even use the array package to create a minipage column type, but it's late and I'm tired.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
%\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[tp]% [hb] not supported
\caption{Converter Operation Under Various Component Failure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|cp{0.4\linewidth}|cp{0.4\linewidth}| } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{4em}{\textbf{Device}}&\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Type of Failure}} \\
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Open Circuit failure (OCF)}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Short Circuit failure (SCF)}}  \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{4em}{\textbf{Main Switch}} 
&\textbullet& Converter operation possible without any additional components.  
&\textbullet& Converter operation possible with fuse incorporated in each phase between switch and inductor of that phase.  \\ 
&\textbullet& Current and voltage stresses on other phases increases. 
&\textbullet& Current and voltage stresses on other phases increases. \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\begin{table*}[tp]% [hb] not supported
\caption{Converter Operation Under Various Component Failure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|p{0.4\linewidth}| p{0.4\linewidth}| } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{4em}{\textbf{Device}}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Type of Failure}} \\
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Open Circuit failure (OCF)}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Short Circuit failure (SCF)}}  \\
\hline
\parbox{4em}{\textbf{Main Switch}} & 
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}% needed to remove gaps at top and bottom
\begin{itemize}
\item Converter operation possible without any additional components.
\item Current and voltage stresses on other phases increases.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{itemize}
\item Converter operation possible with fuse incorporated in each phase between switch and inductor of that phase. 
\item Current and voltage stresses on other phases increases.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: femo]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!